# Favourite (my) sites w/wo tracker

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

So I was thinking of a feature about favourite sites.

For example, I'm interested in `stackoverflow`, `gamedev`, `physics` and `gaming`. Thats 4 out of, at the moment of writing, 71 active sites.

Whenever I want to switch from one to another, I either have to open [All Sites list on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) (and then look/search for my desired one), or, open the upper left Stack Exchange button, switch to all sites tab and scroll to find my desired site.

Well, no problems with all that, but it takes time, especially, if I'm interested only in 4 sites and the quick-selection list seems to be different from site to site.

So, the idea, to have a favourite sites tracker, next to, or implemented inside the "all sites" as the priority sites, therefore shown at the top of the list. Or a separate tracker.

It could as well be transformed into My sites tracker. The difference between My sites and Favourite sites is that "My sites" gets tracked automatically whenever a question/comment/etc. is posted on a site, where Favourite sites are user marked sites he'd wants to follow.

#### With or without tracker:

With this I meant that there could also be a different tracker for these sites. Well, currently the updates work kind of like in "My sites" fashion, but a tracker that'd show how much questions have been added, how much have been added with tags of my interest, etc.

That's my little feature request, what do you think about it?

Comment: They're also listed in the footer

Comment: And footer involves a bit more scrolling, actually, I never notice the footer when browsing through Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can create a filter on stackexchange.com/filters which includes only your sites, to track new questions there. I'm using this (combined with a tag filter): http://stackexchange.com/filters/19305/small-tags-sites

Comment: The footer is less helpful if some of your faves are in beta - nothing overlaps between beta and nonbeta footers. I have the best success just starting to type the url and letting my browser do the rest. I rarely need more than two letters.

Comment: "All sites" in the top bar sorts them for me. There is also the accounts section on user pages.